# Front page of a report

Tags: report

I've been stuck for hours on this since I'm just a beginner on Latex,can anyone help me build this front page :

[image]

Much appreciated! 
Here's what I tried so far :

```
\changepage{+2.5cm}{+5cm}{+0cm}{-2.5cm}{+0cm}{-1cm}{+0cm}{+0cm}{+0cm}

    \begin{center}
\textsc{ENSA/5.GINFO/2013-2014}\\[0.75cm]

        \textsc{\huge \bfseries Rapport du Projet de Fin d'Etudes}\\[1cm]
        \emph{Présenté par : }\\Nom\textsc{Prénom}\\[1cm]

        \textsc{En vue d'obtenir le Diplôme XXXXXXX}\\[0.75cm]
\textsc{Spécialité : XXXXXX}\\[0.75cm]

        \fbox{\parbox[top][2cm][c]{\textwidth}{\begin{center}\Huge \bfseries XXXXXXXXXXXX \end{center}}}\\[1cm]


        \begin{figure}[!htb]
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[scale=.75]{Contenu/Images/logo.png}
            \end{center}
        \end{figure}
        \fbox{\parbox[top][3cm][c]{\textwidth}{\begin{center}\begin{Large}\bsc{Webshore}\end{Large}\\~\\XXXXXXXXXX\\
        \vspace{0.5cm}Maître d'apprentissage: M. XXXXXXXXXX\end{center}}}

        \vfill

        \hrule
        \begin{center}
            Université Claude Bernard - Lyon 1, IUT A
            \begin{figure}[!htb]
                \begin{center}
                    \includegraphics[scale=.25]{Contenu/Images/Logo.png}
                \end{center}
            \end{figure}
            Département Informatique\\
            4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
            XXXXXXXXXXX
        \end{center}
    \end{center}
```

Comment: Please post, what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please also indicate which document class you use and which packages you load. Ideally, you would be providing an MWE (minimum working example) that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to load the `geometry` package with the `pass` option, that will not change the default page geometry, but allows to use `\newgeometry`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} % or your class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\newgeometry{margin=1cm}
\begin{titlepage}
\setlength\fboxsep{-\fboxrule}
\centering

\textsc{ENSA/5.GINFO/2013-2014}\\[0.75cm]

\textsc{\huge \bfseries Rapport du Projet de Fin d'Etudes}\\[1cm]

\emph{Présenté par : }\\Nom \textsc{Prénom}\\[1cm]

\textsc{En vue d'obtenir le Diplôme XXXXXXX}\\[0.75cm]

\textsc{Spécialité : XXXXXX}\\[0.75cm]

\fbox{\parbox[c][2cm][c]{\textwidth}{
  \centering\Huge \bfseries XXXXXXXXXXXX
}}

\vspace{1cm}


\includegraphics[scale=.75]{Contenu/Images/logo.png}\\[1cm]

\fbox{\parbox[c][4cm][c]{\textwidth}{%
  \centering\Large
  \textsc{Webshore}\\[\baselineskip]
  XXXXXXXXXX\\[\baselineskip]
  Maître d'apprentissage: M. XXXXXXXXXX
}}

\vfill

\hrule

\bigskip

Université Claude Bernard - Lyon 1, IUT A\\[1cm]

\includegraphics[scale=.25]{Contenu/Images/Logo.png}\\[1cm]

Département Informatique\\
4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
XXXXXXXXXXX

\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{A title}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `figure` environment should *not* be used here.